# Why LastOrDefault not working in asp.net linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a table that has 4 rows whit this role:

```
Models.tblAssessmentRequest p = new Models.tblAssessmentRequest();
p = biz.Entities.Where(a => a.SuggestionId == SuggestionId).LastOrDefault();
```

but when I execute my program, I got this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Models.tblAssessmentRequest
>   LastOrDefaulttblAssessmentRequest'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression to take last.

```
p = biz.Entities.Where(a => a.SuggestionId == SuggestionId).OrderBy(p => p.SuggestionId).Select(p => p.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(1).Single());
```

Hope it helps you